# How do I push an object in zeroth index of array inside an array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have a backend API which gives data in this format when it is not empty. I have to always push any new data coming from user into `0th` index of first array.

```
[
  [
   {
      name: 'Name 1',
      type: 'Type 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 2',
      type: 'Type 2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: 'Name 4',
      type: 'Type 4'
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 5',
      type: 'Type 5'
    }
  ]
]
```

The below code works fine with non empty data. But, if the API data is empty, it gives *Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error*.

```
  arr: any = [];

  constructor() {}

  submit(data){
    const dataObj = {
      name: 'Test name',
      type: 'Test type',
    }
    this.arr[0].push(dataObj)
    console.log('Result array - ', this.arr)
  }
```

I created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ltqwze?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) using Stackblitz. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if it's empty, and first push an empty array if it is:

```
submit(data){
  const dataObj = {
    name: 'Test name',
    type: 'Test type',
  }

  if (!this.arr[0]) {
    this.arr.push([]);
  }

  this.arr[0].push(dataObj);
  console.log('Result array - ', this.arr);
}
```

You are also saying you want to push it to the `0th index of first array`. So this solves the 'first array' part. If you really want to push it to the `0th` index of the first array, you use `unshift`:

```
this.arr[0].unshift(dataObj);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Checking for `arr[0]` helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unshift for it.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.unshift(0); // [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

Please note that it is a mutating function.

You can also use:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
[0].concat(arr); // [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

This doesn't mutate the existing array.

Answer (score 0):

There are suprisingly multiple ways to enter an element in the 0th position. You could achieve it with `push()` and `shift()` like other answers have mentioned. You could also do it with [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
arr1.splice(0, 0, 4); // <-- enter in pos. 0
console.log('Position 0: ', arr1);

const arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
arr2.splice(1, 0, 4); // <-- enter in pos. 1
console.log('Position 1:', arr2);
```